# <Script> vs. external file for button.style.cursor

Tags: javascript, styles, mouse-cursor

I have the following code both included in  separate file (random.js) and as part of a  tag in the random.html file itself. The code works as long as its in the  tags but not in the separate .js file. Is there an initialization routine that needs to happen first?

```
var button = document.querySelector("button");
button.style.cursor = "pointer";
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your `document.querySelector("button")` will get an array of all the `<button>` elements on your page. From your code, it looks as if you expect only one button, so try using an id, like "#button" instead of just "button".
2. If that doesn't help, the JS should be included at the *bottom* of the page. Make sure you are doing that.
3. If this still doesn't work, try wrapping all you code in a `window.onready` function.

Comment: #1 is wrong. `querySelector` just returns the first matching element, `querySelectorAll` gets a list of all of them.